# Remove default packages' caches

Tags: adb, default-applications

I removed a package installed default via this command (with adb):

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 the_package
```

Because of `-k`, the command does not remove the package's cache. How can I remove its cache after removing package's itself? I can't use the command again without the option because I have removed the package and now I do not have it.

Comment: You can try `pm clear <package name>`

Comment: Thank you. It is what I want. But can I get list of packages I have removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to uninstall the data directories of an already uninstalled app by executing:

```
pm clear <package name>
```

respectively on recent devices using cmd command

```
cmd package clear <package name>
cmd package clear --user 0 <package name>
```

This will delete all files (for the selected user) in `/data/data/<package name>`. Only the empty directory itself will remain and the app package name will not be removed from the list of uninstalled apps.

If you don't remember the correct package name you can list all packages including those uninstalled by the command

```
cmd package list package -u
```

Comment: How can I use `cmd` command? Should I install a new package for using this?
I use debian.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh No `cmd` is just the replacement for `pm`. It is only available on the Android device (so they are only available inside `adb shell`). If your device is too old and does not have the `cmd` command try the same arguments with `pm`. Most likely this will work, too.

Comment: Thank you. I found `pm list packages -u` command that lists removed packages to and used `pm clear <package>` command to clear their caches.